# LEDA library installation

Tags: c++, leda

I have downloaded LEDA free edition from this website
http://www.algorithmic-solutions.com/leda/ledak/index.htm

**First quetion:**
I want to use this library with my project in VS2010 ide, but i didn't really catch from installation notes, how can i install this library on windows platform.
There were already some static libs (you can see them on the image), which i added to my project  with appropriate headers. But that, i suggest, is not a right way. So i will be glad if you will briefly describe the steps, which i should make to compile this library...
The root library directory looks like this
[image]

**Second question:**

In leda's installation guide i can see two main sections:

1.) CONFIGURATION/INSTALLATION FOR UNIX 
2.) CONFIGURATION/INSTALLATION for MS Visual C++

In "CONFIGURATION/INSTALLATION for MS Visual C++" i can see the following:

4. Go to the LEDA main directory (at the command prompt used above).
5. Type: lconfig msc [dll] [ ml | mld | md | mdd | mt | mtd ]

I'am sorry, i have never seriously used UNIX based systems, but i always thought that MS Visual C++ is a thing, strongly connected with Windows, and lconfig is a unix command?
So i confused, this guide is for unix or for windows or ...?

Thank you, sorry for possibly stupid questions.

Comment: What, LEDA still exists? Isn't that from 20 years ago?! I thought it's been dead for more than a decade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LEDA "free" edition does not include source code.  They sell the source code for users who want to modify / compile it.  What you have downloaded can be used by including the .h in \incl and linking against the appropriate .lib files.  It appears that the package gives you several .lib files to cover all the options of static linking or dynamic linking.

The lconfig instructions are for when you do have the source code, and you want to control which configuration of dll/lib gets built.

Answer (score 1):

"`lconfig`" is *not* a standard or even niche UNIX tool; a quick google suggests it's something that actually comes with LEDA itself. Since you've downloaded it, you ought to see it someplace in the bundle.

Comment: So i found some other mentions about lconfig, which did not connected with LEDA itself. And there are no files with name "lconfig" or smth like that in distribution